# Use MySQL CURDATE() and CURTIME() to return results up and coming but not passed

Tags: mysql

Users of my site will be able to create events. They will set a date and a time separately. The event will be saved to a mysql database containing separate date and time columns.

I would like to query the database to return events which are up and coming but not passed. i.e. the event date is today or in the future and if the event date is today check the the time of the event hasn't passed.

I don't know the syntax for this and I cant seem to find it anywhere.

If anyone knows a good way to do this I'd very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to express this efficiently in SQL and make use of any indexes you have on the date and/or time columns would be a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE date_column > current_date()
OR (date_column = current_date() AND time_column > current_time())
```

Depending on which version of MySQL you are using and how your table is indexed there is a small chance that the optimizer would prefer the query expressed as two SELECTs UNIONed together to avoid the OR:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE date_column > current_date()
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE date_column = current_date()
AND time_column > current_time()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where concat_ws(' ',date_field,time_field) > now()
```

Why don't you use a datetime field?

Comment: That query may return the correct results, but it would be slow because it does a table scan instead of an index scan.

Comment: Hi Ike. Thanks for your comment. I'm not an expert of mysql optimization :)

Answer (score 0):

in pseudocode

```
if ((date > today) OR (date == today AND time > now))
```